# Can I verify if a class is correctly created?

Tags: c#, class, xamarin

I know this may be a stupid question, but I am really new in this programming world so there's a lot of stuff I don't understand or don't know how to do.

I'm starting to learn a little bit about C#, and I'm trying to create a class, so far I think I'm good, but there's no way to 'check' if I did it well... when you create a solution in Xamarin Studio on OSX, you press CMD+Enter and the solution will compile and you'll see the result of all the code you wrote, but I don't know if there's some kind of procedure like it or some kind of tip to check if the class I created is OK.

Comment: Yea, of course there is: in Visual Studio, menu Build > Build Solution.

Comment: I saw an option 'build class.cs' but is greyed out, in fact all the build menú is greyed out [I'm not using VB but Xamarin]. Is the class suposed to be part of a solution so it can be built? I just created a new class file and started to practice, maybe that's the reason why the menu is greyed?

Comment: What does "is OK" mean (to you)?

Comment: I guess Ok for me is if the class will create the object correctly, You see when you start the debugger it will tell you if there's a { missing, or if there's a problem with a var. but I guess the only way to check it would be creating an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your code compiles, but does it really work is what it seems you are asking.

It sounds like what you are looking for is unit testing. Go read up on that and test-driven development.

For a small summary, you decide in advance of what the output of your object should be, and write tests that check that the output is correct under all reasonable inputs. Then you code the class against that test. Finally, you test it. And then, every time you change the code, (to add a feature or fix a bug), you run the SAME unit tests, with possibly new additions, and verify that they still pass.

The quality of the tests themselves is now the limiting factor in the quality of your code, but you learn how to write good tests when your code does something unexpected, you debug it, and realize what else you should have tested for.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point somewhere in your class and step through the code.

Comment: I tried to use a breakpoint but it seems they just work with solutions, or with classes that are part of a solution.